# How do you construct a solr query to query a particular datasource?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using LucidWorks and I need to restrict my search on a solr database to a particular datasource.

How do you construct a solr query to query a particular datasource?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Are you trying to say querying to a particular collection/core?

Comment: No. I have multiple datasources inside a single collection. Sometimes when doing a search I want to limit searches to a single datasource (or a selection of datasources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to index the datasource itself, then you can add a filter subquery `fq` to the main query so you can restrict your search as you want.

Say for example that documents datasource are indexed in a field called 'src' and you want to query only documents from 'val_1' and documents from 'val_2' datasources, then appending a filter subquery should do the trick e.g. :

`.../solr/yourCollection/yourSearchHandler?q=*:*&fq=(src:val_1+OR+src:val_2)`

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect answer.

For completeness, in LucidWorks the data_source_name is already searchable so you just have to add a filter query such as:

fq=data_source_name:mydatasourcename